# JS - Enable ghost element effect with preventDefault call

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, mouseevent

I'm trying to implement operation, I want to drag element from a list of `img` tags to different `svg:rect` containers.

Using `mousedown` and `mouseup` is sufficient for understand which `img` is picked from the list and in which `svg:rect` is dropped.

The code is the following:

```
<body>

<div style="border: 1px solid black">
    <svg width="300" height="100">
        <rect id="container" width="60" height="60"></rect>
        <rect id="container2" x="70" width="60" height="60"  fill="salmon"></rect>
    </svg>
</div>

<div id="list">
    <img id="item" src="img/cat.png" width="64" />
</div>

<script>

    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    const container2 = document.getElementById('container2');
    const item = document.getElementById('item');

    let drag = null

    item.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('mouse down from IMG');
        drag = e.target;
    });

    container.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Container 1', drag);
        drag = null;
    });

    container2.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Container 2', drag);
        drag = null;
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that with `e.preventDefault()` in the `img` event listener I lost **the ghost element effect** while user drag the `img`.

How to enable that and use `preventDefault()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search and tests, I came up with two possible solutions:

**First solution**: don't use html5 drag and drop at all.

Instead use `mousedown` applied to the drag element and `mouseup` applied to the drop element. In `mousedown` event the `preventDefault()` call is needed. This remove the ghost element effect while user is dragging. In order to reintroduce that effect you need to build your own ghost element with the css properties `pointer-events: none` and `position: absolute`.

**Second solution**: use partially drag and drop html5 feature.

Set `dragstart` event on your drag element (img) and `drop` and `dragover` on your drop element (svg). Check `e.target` in the `drop` event and you have the reference of your `svg:rect` element.

An example here:
https://gist.github.com/EduBic/49e36485c70c5a6d15df7db1861333de

**N.B.** remember to add the other event and to manage other cases.

Comment: Well the Second solution with e.target looks perfect ! Good job ! I'm going to edit my answer if I can.

Answer (score 1):

The ghost element effect comes from the default `draggable` property of `<img>`

Using `ondragstart` on the image and `ondrop` on an other element would be perfect. See [that exemple](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondrop).

Sadly it's not supported on `rect` elements. You can do something with the `onmouseover` event on the `rect` elements but the user will need to move the mouse after the drop for it to work.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const container2 = document.getElementById('container2');
const item = document.getElementById('item');

    let drag = null

function dragImg (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        console.log('ondrag IMG');
        drag = e.target;
    };

// Not working
function ondrop1 (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Container 1', drag);
        drag = null;
    };

// Not working
function ondrop2 (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Container 2', drag);
        drag = null;
    };
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
    <svg width="300" height="100">
        <rect id="container" onmouseover="ondrop1(event)" width="60" height="60"></rect>
        <rect id="container2" onmouseover="ondrop2(event)" x="70" width="60" height="60"  fill="salmon"></rect>
    </svg>
</div>

<div id="list">
    <img ondragstart="dragImg(event)" id="item" src="https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.22.1/img/champion/Velkoz.png" width="64" />
</div>
```

[EDIT] If you want to keep using `rect` elements with a perfect solution you will need to use `ondrop` on the svg and you will find the `rect` element under `event.target` [see documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I've found two solutions (with mouseover they are 3) that I described in my answer.